# Django - Only ONE specific static file GET 404

Tags: python, django

When refactoring the templates of a Django Project, the response of ONE SPECIFIC .js static file is 404:

Terminal:

```
[08/Dec/2016 13:54:43] "GET /static/new_site/js/general_scripts.js' HTTP/1.1" 404 1718
[08/Dec/2016 13:54:43] "GET /static/new_site/js/core.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 758545
```

HTML

```
...
<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/general_scripts.js' %}'"></script>
<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/core.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Paths:

```
.../static/new_site/js/general_scripts.js
.../static/new_site/js/core.min.js
```

Django==1.8.17

Ubuntu 16.04 (Both files have the same permissions)

OBS: Pycharm IDE is aware of both files

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes the difference or not, but you have an extra apostrophe in your code: `<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/general_scripts.js' %}'"></script>` should be `<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/general_scripts.js' %}"></script>`. The error occurs on the outside of the curly bracket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove a `'` from your line (`%}'"`):

```
<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/general_scripts.js' %}"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="{% static 'new_site/js/general_scripts.js' %}'"></script>
```